# Does a code that combines single() with yield make any sense?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, refactoring, yield

I came across a code which should return the single object expected in a list, this code has an iterator block which yields the found items, i have simplified the case in the following example:

```
private static void Methode_A()
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", NumberList(2, 8).Single());     
}

private static IEnumerable<int> NumberList(int min, int max)
{
    while (min < max)
        yield return min++;        
}
```

Does it make any sense or are there any known benefits of combining `Single()` with `yield` over just building the list and asserting it contains one single element?

Comment: "While i expected the code to break after the first exception (on the second found item) it keeps running and throws exceptions for all found items after the first one. why is that?" How are you returning execution to `Single()` after the first exception is thrown?

Comment: I think you mean to use `First()` which yields the first of *one or more* items. `Single()` yields the first item but throws an exception if there's more than one. The code you show us can't "keep running" after an exception.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I didnt write the code, i found it while refactoring the class, it is using the Single, guess someone wanted to spare the check for the item count.

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps running"? The code you show us can't do that! Where is the exception handler that is ignoring the exception and retrying? ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson forget it witht hte excepotion, it was my mistaken interpretation of the debugger behaviour. i edited the question.

Comment: Then it makes no sense to write `Methode_A()` since it will always throw an exception - *unless* it is part of a unit test which is checking that an exception *is* thrown. But this has nothing to do with the use of `yield`.

Comment: @CloudyMarble I'll let someone else answer, but my understanding of deferred execution means that this is, in fact, more efficient than generating the entire list and checking the length. This is `O(1)` because of deferred execution, while generating the entire list is linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this works is the following:

1. You call `NumberList(2, 8).Single()`
2. The execution flow enters the `while` loop for the first time and returns the first result (2).
3. The execution flow continues on the second iteration of the loop and it returns a second element (3)
4. The `.Single` method immediately throws an exception and stops the execution because it expected that there will be only one element contained in the enumerator

On the other hand if you call `NumberList(2, 8).First()` here's what will happen:

1. The execution flow enters the `while` loop for the first time and returns the first result (2).
2. The execution flow no longer continues in the `while` loop because one element was already returned and this element will be the result of the call

Comment: Yeah I bet he meant to use `First()`

Comment: I think you guys both misread OP... or maybe I did. He seems to state explicitly that he's not getting the behavior described above for `Single()` and he's asking why.

Comment: @roliu, get cannot get something else from this code snippet other than the behavior explained in my answer. If he does then this is not his real code.

Comment: @roliu Well look at the OP's code. It's bound to throw an exception. And it can't "keep running" afterwards - that just won't happen.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov This is not my code as roliu saied, i found it while i was refactoring the class, i am just trying to make sure if it makes any special sense before i refactore it.

Comment: @CloudyMarble, if this is not your real code then what is your question? Sorry I must have misread it.

Comment: I fhte combination as is makes any sense, the assumption that the list should have only onle element is right, but the implementation as is does it make any sense?

Comment: Let say is it a good way to make sure the list has only one element?

Comment: I have no idea. It will depend on what you are trying to achieve. The `.Single` method is useful when you are calling it on some collection that you filtered by some unique code and you know that there must be at most one element (0 or 1 elements). For example `collection.Single(x => x.Id == 5)`. On the other hand the `.First` extension method is used when you just want to retrieve the first element. The `NumberList` method seems pretty valid implementation. It's just that there's the `Enumerable.Range(start, count)` method that you probably weren't aware of and reinvented the wheel.

Comment: Forget First, its not an option and would produce wrong behviour, is itmore performant to use thie yield to build the list because of deferred execution in this case where i need to ensure my list has only one element.